# Problem after finding tag contents, cannot sum

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to pull the tag contents from an html page and sum the contents (which are strings), here's my code so far

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('Enter- ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the span tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
   # Look at the parts of a tag
   print('Sum of Contents:',sum(int(tag.contents[0])))
```

without the `sum(int())` it correctly returns a string of the values, but I'm trying to change the string to integer and sum it. I'm assuming I messed something up that is quite basic?

```
Contents: 97
Contents: 97
Contents: 90
Contents: 90
Contents: 88
Contents: 87
Contents: 87
Contents: 80
Contents: 79
Contents: 79
Contents: 78
Contents: 76
Contents: 76
Contents: 72
Contents: 72
Contents: 66
Contents: 66
Contents: 65
Contents: 65
Contents: 64
Contents: 61
Contents: 61
Contents: 59
Contents: 58
Contents: 57
Contents: 57
Contents: 54
Contents: 51
Contents: 49
Contents: 47
Contents: 40
Contents: 38
Contents: 37
Contents: 36
Contents: 36
Contents: 32
Contents: 25
Contents: 24
Contents: 22
Contents: 21
Contents: 19
Contents: 18
Contents: 18
Contents: 14
Contents: 12
Contents: 12
Contents: 9
Contents: 7
Contents: 3
Contents: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using list comprehension to first collect all the integers and then sum them

```
summation = sum([int(tag.contents[0]) for tag in tags])
print('Sum of Contents:',summation)
```

If you don't want to use the list comprehension, you can use

```
summation = []
for tag in tags:
    summation.append(int(tag.contents[0]))
print('Sum of Contents:', sum(summation))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tag_search.py", line 14, in <module>
    print('Sum of Contents:',sum(map(int(tag.contents[0]))))
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.

Comment: @Jon: Try out my edited answer and see if it works for you